# I want to calculate mean and standard deviation from user input, but it says saying data type error in deviation function

Tags: python

I want to create a program that will ask for input until a new line is entered. The user input will be in a list. Then it will calculate the mean and standard deviation of inputs. I wrote the following code, but it shows some data type errors for stddev function.

```
def main():
   print("Enter the data, one value per line.\nEnd by entering empty line.")
   a = []
   prompt = ""
   line = input(prompt)

   while line:
       a.append(float(line))
       line = input(prompt)
   meanfunction(a)
   stdev(a)

   print("The mean of given data was: ",meanfunction(a))
   print("The standard deviation of given data was: ",stdev(a))
def meanfunction(data):
    average = sum(data) / len(data)
    average_f = "{:.2f}".format(average)
    return average_f

def variance(data):
    n = len(data)
    mean = sum(data) / n
    deviations = [(x - mean) ** 2 for x in data]
    variance = sum(deviations) / (n)
    variance_f = "{:.2f}".format(variance)
    return variance_f
 def stdev(data):
    import math
    var = variance(data)
    std_dev = math.sqrt(var)
    return std_dev
 if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Having fixed your indentation, the issue seems to be your format string in `variance(data)` just before the return line. You use the output of `variance` as an input in the `stdev` function but `variance` returns a string output. It looks like `meanfunction` does the same thing.

Generally, for these mathematical functions, it would be best to just have them keep to what they are supposed to do: return a number, like you already do with `stdev`'s return. Deal with making it pretty when it comes to actually printing it to the screen.

Also making a variable names more descriptive than "a" is nice, especially when we come to look at our old code! Lastly we usually want to put imports at the very top.

```py
import math


def main():
    print("Enter the data, one value per line.\n"
          "End by entering an empty line.")
    user_values = []
    prompt = ""
    line = input(prompt)

    while line:
        user_values.append(float(line))
        line = input(prompt)
    meanfunction(user_values)
    stdev(user_values)

    print(f"The mean of the given data was: {meanfunction(user_values):.2f} ")
    print(f"The standard deviation of the given data was:  {stdev(user_values):.2f}")


def meanfunction(data):
    average = sum(data) / len(data)
    return average


def variance(data):
    n = len(data)
    mean = sum(data) / n
    deviations = [(x - mean) ** 2 for x in data]
    variance = sum(deviations) / (n - 1)
    return variance


def stdev(data):
    var = variance(data)
    std_dev = math.sqrt(var)
    return std_dev


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Good improvements. It also doesn't need those lonely `meanfunction` and `stdev` calls that aren't assigned to anything. (Also, the asker has fixed their indentation.)